# IFS '\n' not working in AIX box

Tags: shell

I am trying to read a file which has several lines and print it as it is.
But my new line in IFS is not working as expected. This is in AIX.

Below is my script,

```
#!/bin/ksh

#set -x
old_IFS=$IFS      # save the field separator
IFS=$'\n'
LABELFILE=/home/david/label.txt
OUTPUT_FILE=/home/david/label_out.txt

for i in $(cat $LABELFILE)
do
echo "$i" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

#### label.txt

```
Hello nancy
naghu naghu
Hello navy
You are naughty
Good niece
```

My Output file(label_out.txt->

```
Hello
a
cy

aghu
aghu
Hello
avy
You are
aughty
Good
iece
```

Expected output->

```
Hello nancy
naghu naghu
Hello navy
You are naughty
Good niece
```

Comment: Inside single quotes, `\n` means backslash and `n`.  Inside double quotes, it might mean newline, but (except in `bash`) usually doesn't.

Comment: Separately from the single-quoted `'\n'` issue (for which you have the workaround), the whole `for i in $(cat $file)` stuff is plain weird.  You'd do far better with `read` plus I/O redirection.  (Note that you're forcing the shell to read the whole of the file in memory, and then dole it out one line at a time, instead of just letting it read one line at a time.)

Comment: It depends. The `read` builtin needs to leave the file pointer at the correct place after each execution, so it will tend to do many more system calls (when reading from pipes, reading one byte at a time is required and it commonly happens also when reading from other types of file). If the file is large enough that the overhead from forking `cat` can be amortized and small enough that it fits into memory comfortably, the `for i in $(cat $file)` approach may well be faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
IFS='
'
```

(Just a carriage return there, no extra whitespace.)